# tiva c I2C one master multiple slaves do not work

Tags: c, arm, embedded, i2c

I was trying to create project which use I2C protocol to control multiple node. When I am trying to control only one node address on the bus, my code works perfectly, but when I tried to talk with two nodes, only first command work on all over the system. This is my driver using keil IDE and tiva c < TM4C123GH6PM >

```
#include "I2C.h"


/********************* Functions *************************/

void i2c0Enable(i2cState state)
{
/*************** enable I2C configuration ****************/
/* enable I2C clock */
    SYSCTL->RCGCI2C |=(1 << 0 ); // true
/* enable portB clock */
    SYSCTL->RCGCGPIO |= (1 << 1 ); //true
    /* configure alternative function registser of portB to work as I2C */
    //GPIOB->AFSEL  &=~((1 << 2 ) | (1 << 3 ));
    GPIOB->AFSEL  |=((1 << 2 ) | (1 << 3 )); //true
    /* enable digital */    
    //GPIOB->DEN &= ~((1 << 2 ) | ( 1 << 3 ));
    GPIOB->DEN |= ((1 << 2 ) | ( 1 << 3 )); //true
/* enable open drain on pin3 of portB (SDL) */
    GPIOB->ODR |=(1 << 3) ; //true

/* disable pullup and pull down */  
    //GPIOB->PUR &=~((1 << 2 ) | (1 << 3 )); // not needed  
/* disable puldown resistance */    
    //GPIOB->PDR &=~((1 << 2 ) | (1 << 3 )); // not needed 
/* configure pin[2,3] of portB to work as SDL,SCL */
    GPIOB->PCTL |= ( 0x3 << 12 ) | (0x3 << 8) ;  // true

/* configure GPIOCR register to let other settings to take effect */
    //GPIOB->CR |= ( 1 <<3 ) | (1 << 2) ; // deleted if any error


/*******************************************************/

    /* configure bus speed depending on i2c state*/
    /* all the calculations are depending one the equation */
    /* TPR = (System Clock/(2*(SCL_LP + SCL_HP)*SCL_CLK))-1; */
    /* where SCL_LP and SCL_HP  are fixed to the values 4 and 6 respectivelly */
    /* and the HS bit in I2CMTPR register is 0 for all modes but high speed mode */
    switch(state)
    {
        case STANDARD :
            /* speed is 100kbps */  
            I2C0->MTPR = (SystemCoreClock / (2000000))-1 ;
            break;
        case FAST :
            /* speed is 400kbps */
            I2C0->MTPR = (SystemCoreClock / (8000000))-1 ;
            break;
        case FASTPLUS :
            /* speed is 1Mbps */
            I2C0->MTPR = (SystemCoreClock / (20000000))-1 ;
            break;
        case HIGHSPEED :
            /* speed is 3.33Mbps */
            I2C0->MTPR = (SystemCoreClock / (19980000))-1 ;
         /* setting HS bit in both registers to run in high speed mode */
            I2C0->MTPR |= (1 << 7 ) ;
            setBit(I2C0->MCS , BIT4) ; 
            break;
    }

}
```

master sending function

```
void i2cSendMaster(uint8_t data,uint8_t slaveAddress)
{
    /* Initialize the I2C Master by writing the I2CMCR register with */
    /* a value of 0x0000.0010 */
    I2C0->MCR |=(1 << 4)  ; // true
    /* setting speed to standard mode */
    //I2C0->MTPR = 7 ; // true
    /* applying master slave address with default write operation */
    I2C0 ->MSA |=(slaveAddress << 1 ); //true
    I2C0 ->MSA &=~(1 << 0 ); // true
    I2C0 -> MDR = data ;   //true
    /* check BUSBSY bit to confirm that bus is free to write on */
    // while( (I2C0->MCS & (1 << 6)) != 0 ) ;
    /*Initiate a single byte transmit of the data from Master to Slave by writing the I2CMCS register
    with a value of 0x0000.0007 (STOP, START, RUN).*/
    I2C0 -> MCS = 7 ; // true <<<<
    /* checking Bus busy bit  to check if the transmission is complete*/ 
    //while( (I2C0->MCS & (0x00000040)) == 1 ) ; ///
    while( (I2C0->MCS & (1 << 0)) == 1 ) ; // true ( check contoller buzzy state )
    /* new code */
    /* check if data sent with  errors */
    if((I2C0->MCS & (1 << 1)) == 1 )
    {
            SYSCTL ->RCGCGPIO |=(1 << 5 );
            GPIOF  ->DEN |=((1 << 1) | ( 1 << 2 ) | (1 << 3 ));
            GPIOF  ->DIR |=((1 << 1) | ( 1 << 2 ) | (1 << 3 ));
            GPIOF  ->DATA |=(1 << 1) ;
    }
    else
    {
            SYSCTL ->RCGCGPIO |=(1 << 5 );
            GPIOF  ->DEN |=((1 << 1) | ( 1 << 2 ) | (1 << 3 ));
            GPIOF  ->DIR |=((1 << 1) | ( 1 << 2 ) | (1 << 3 ));
            GPIOF  ->DATA |=(1 << 3) ;
    }

}
```

slave receive code

```
uint8_t i2cSlaveReceive(void)   
{
    uint8_t data ;
    /* Initialize the I2C Slave by writing the I2CMCR register with */
    /* a value of 0x0000.0010 */
    /* set SFE bit ; */
    I2C0->MCR = 0x20 ;

    /* set slave own address */
    I2C0 ->SOAR = 0x3b ;
    /* enable slave operation */
    setBit(I2C0->SCSR , BIT0 ) ;
    /* check if any valid data received */
    while((I2C0->SRIS & (1 << BIT0 )) != 1);
//  while(!checkBit(I2C0 ->SRIS,BIT0 ));
    /* receive data */
    data = I2C0->SDR ;
    /* set enable acknowledge with NACK in response */
    //setBit(I2C0 ->SACKCTL , BIT0 );
    //setBit(I2C0 ->SACKCTL , BIT1 );
    /* clearing received data flag */
    setBit(I2C0 ->SICR , BIT0 );
    /* returning data received */
    return data ;

}
```

Comment: We are no debugging service. See [ask].

Comment: To be fair, @Olaf, that is precisely what we are - he has written code, it doesn't work, much better question than many lame posts on here. OTOH as this must involve hardware, it may be impossible to actually answer.

Comment: @barny: You want to recap site-rules, e.g. [ask]. We are **not** a free debugging service, but a Q&A site for **specific** problems. This becomes more important even for embedded questions, as we most likely don't have the same hardware and/or other tools available.

Comment: Could you add a piece of code showing how it works with one slave and it doesn't work with a second slave ?

Answer (score 0):

When passing the address there is no need to do an `OR` operation.

```
I2C0 ->MSA |=(slaveAddress << 1 );
```

Only pass the slave address

```
I2C0 ->MSA =(slaveAddress << 1 );
```